# Evaluate integral over complex path numerically to show that $C_\infty$ is equivalent to $-I$

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, matlab, contour-integration, complex-integration

I would like to evaluate

$$C_\infty = \int_{R = -a}^{R = a} H_0^{(1)}(z) e^{-izt} dz $$

where $H_0^{(1)}(z)$ is the Hankel function of the first kind, $a \rightarrow \infty$, and

$$ z = R - i \sqrt{a^2 - R^2}$$

is the path of integration beneath the real axis.

The function $H_0^{(1)}(z)$ has only one pole (at $z=0$) which is removable. Therefore, by the residue theorem, $C_\infty + I = 0$, where

$$ I = -\int_{-a}^{a} H_0^{(1)}(R) e^{-iRt} dR. $$

When I evaluate $C_\infty$ numerically however, I experience some difficulty. $I$ on the other hand converges fine.

I have tried to evaluate it by breaking the integral into small subintervals, applying Gaussian quadrature to each, and then adding the real and imaginary parts together. Matlab's `integral()` function for adaptive quadrature also does not work so I include it here as an example:

```
a = 1000;
t = 2;

%% C PATH
f = @(z) besselh(0,1,z).*exp(-1j*z*t);
z = @(R) R - sqrt(a^2 - R.^2)*1j;
dzdr = @(R) 1 - 1/2*(a^2 - R.^2).^(-1/2).*(-2.*R)*1j;
g_C = integral(@(R) f(z(R)).*dzdr(R), a, -a)
g_C_2 = integral(@(R) real(f(z(R))).*dzdr(R), a, -a) + 1j*integral(@(R) imag(f(z(R))).*dzdr(R), a, -a)
g_C_3 = integral(@(R) real(f(z(R)).*dzdr(R)), a, -a) + 1j*integral(@(R) imag(f(z(R)).*dzdr(R)), a, -a) 


%% I PATH
f = @(z) besselh(0,1,z).*exp(-1j*z*t);
z = @(R) R;
dzdr = @(R) 1;
g_I = integral(@(R) f(z(R)).*dzdr(R), a, -a)
```

Output:

```
g_C = NaN + NaNi
g_C_2 = NaN + NaNi
g_C_3 = NaN + NaNi
g_I = -0.0000 + 2.3188i
```

Is it possible to perform this $C_\infty$ integration numerically?

**Other things that I have tried:**

- using the asymptotic form of $H_0^{(1)}(z)$ = $\sqrt{2/\pi z} e^{i(z - \pi/4)} $ to deal with large $-i$ arguments, which gives an incorrect answer. Probably because it is not accurate enough for the small argument components.
- Mapping the integral over $\theta = 0$ to $\pi$ using $z = a(\cos{\theta} - i\sin{\theta})$.

Comment: Why are you taking real part only of $f(z(R))$? $z'(R)$ also is complex.

Comment: @uranix: For `g_C_2` I was using the relationship $g = \int a + ib \, dz = \int a \, dz + i\int b \, dz$. Taking $g = \int a + ib \, dr = \int a \, dr + i\int b \, dr$ (i.e. including the $z'$ term inside the `real()` and `imag()` functions also returns `g_C_3 = NaN + NaNi`.

Comment: Mathematica numerically integrates both, but
$$
g_C = 0.0247879 - 0.00470972 i\\
g_{C2} = -7.33294\cdot 10^{-14} - 2.31881 i
$$

Comment: @uranix: hmmm thanks for that. Maybe Mathematica is implementing some kind of mapping function to deal with the $z'(R)$ singularities at $\pm a$...

Comment: I'm afraid your function is highly oscillatory and that may be the problem. Also i'm wondering why does not residue theorem hold in this case

Comment: Here's your problem: besselh(0,1,-100j) = 2.1475e+42 - 2.9645e-45i, 
besselh(0,1,-1000j) = Inf. You need to approximate $H^{(1)}_0(z)e^{i t z}$

Comment: @uranix: I tried that already to no avail by using the asymptotic form (see above), and also breaking it up such that the asymptotic form is only used for large $-i$ parts... It appears like since the large $-i$ parts go to zero anyway (due to the $e^{-izt}$ going to zero faster than $H_0^{(1)}(z)$ goes to $\infty$ at $t=2$) the information must be somehow stored very close to the $\pm a$ parts which would otherwise be negligible when the integration is performed along the real axis.

Comment: Do you have ideas why $I \neq -C_\infty$ even for small $a = 10$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $H^{(1)}_0(z)$ used in Matlab and Mathematica has a branch cut over the line $(-\infty, 0]$. Thus your real line integration does not give the answer you're looking for. Fix your code with

```
%% I PATH
f = @(z) besselh(0,1,z).*exp(-1j*z*t);
z = @(R) R - 1e-20j; % under branch cut
dzdr = @(R) 1;
g_I = integral(@(R) f(z(R)).*dzdr(R), a, -a)
```

Next, to overcome the problem with large negative imaginary values of $z$ you can use the special variant of `besselh(nu,K,Z,1)` function that computes $H^{(1)}_0(z)e^{-iz}$

```
%% C PATH
f = @(z) besselh(0,1,z,1).*exp(-1j*z*(t-1));
z = @(R) R - sqrt(a^2 - R.^2)*1j;
dzdr = @(R) 1 - 1/2*(a^2 - R.^2).^(-1/2).*(-2.*R)*1j;
g_C = integral(@(R) f(z(R)).*dzdr(R), a, -a)
```

Comment: Good answer. However, what if the path that I am interested in is the original definition of the I path (i.e. $z=R$). To instead take the $C$ path above the real axis would be problematic since it would tend to infinity with large $+i$... Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Eksze Path $z = R$ is not well defined. The function $H^{(1)}_0(z)$ has a discontinuity in every point $z < 0$ (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). Assuming you want the $z = R + 0i$ path. Well, you still can pick *any* contour, not the half circle one. You can take an ellipse with real semiaxis equal to $a$ and imaginary semiaxis equal to $1$.